# Can OpenCV decode H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to use OpenCV (python bindings) to connect to a UDP multicast and recover individual received frames for post-processing.

I can connect to my multicast via VLC, and VLC displays the broadcast with no issues at all. VLC reports that the codec it uses for decoding is H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10).

When I try to decode using OpenCV, I do see my video stream, but many frames appear fragmented. The frames appear as if the last line of pixels just got repeated to fill in the rest of the image (sometimes 75% or more of the whole image). OpenCV reports decoding errors (error while decoding MB ...., bytestream ).

Is there any way to force OpenCV to use whatever codec VLC is using? I tried to specify the specific codec to use in my code for OpenCV but it seems to have no effect.

The code I am using is below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import cv

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv.CV_FOURCC('A','V','C','1')) 
cwi=cap.open(r'myurlandport')

counter = 0

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()


    counter += 1

    if counter % 30 == 0:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, please first try to rebuild opencv with ffmpeg support, that should cover most common codecs.

Comment: Is FFMPEG not already included with the binaries? In the bin folder I see opencv_ffmpeg246.dll which makes me think it was already compiled with ffmpeg?

Comment: ah, yes, sorry, it seems it is as default.  So the question is whether that ffmpeg lib is build with the VLC x264 support?   https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#x264 .

Comment: also, if your on windows, opencv maybe trying to use dshow, directx, even though ffmpeg is included, since that is also default.

Comment: Any way to override this?

Comment: I think it is trying to use ffmpeg since if I remove the ffmpeg.dll from my python directory, opencv cannot decode at all, and I see no images at all.

Comment: strange.  did you try waiting longer cv2.waitKey(100) ?

Comment: Just tried, still get the same issue.

Comment: okay, well at the mo. i can't even get the streaming working in vlc! i just get grey screen there also, so that's me done for night, sorry :/. +1 for good question!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56968/discussion-between-sergiy-and-qed).

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked (OpenCV 2.4.9) ffmpeg build used in OpenCV did not utilize UDP protocol. It doesn't buffer received packets for later use. More info here:
http://code.opencv.org/issues/2235

EDIT:
In order to force TCP mode, edit opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp line 538

```
int err=avformat_open_input(&ic, _filename, NULL, NULL);
```

adding tcp:

```
 AVDictionary *d = NULL;
 av_dict_set(&d, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
 int err=avformat_open_input(&ic, _filename, NULL, &d);
```